# Dynamically creating an expression with parameterized returning properties

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, lambda, entity-framework-core

I need to make a method which will make and return an expression that I can use latter in LINQ in order to get some data from the database.

I have an entity class:

```
public class Rule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string C1 { get; set; }
    public string C2 { get; set; }
    public string C3 { get; set; }
    public string C4 { get; set; }       
}
```

And the method that receives two arguments which are names of Rule class properties(columns):

```
private Expression<Func<Rule, object>> GetExpression(string colX, string colY)
{
    // Expression<Func<Rule, object>> exp = x => new { X = x.C1, Y = x.C3 };
    // return exp;
}
```

Is there any way to set expression returning object's properties dynamically to `colX` and `colY` which are names of the `Rule`'s class properties?

Comment: Check out [DynamicLinq](https://dynamic-linq.net/)

Comment: And there are many more similar posts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can create an Expression in  runtime based on your logic.

But a simpler way and recommended way is to use [`System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) library out of the box. With this library it's possible to write Dynamic LINQ queries (string based) on an `IQueryable`.

Comment: This is very common for making APIs

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

We have 2 possibility.

1. dynamic linq library
2. reflection